# Deleting first node of linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

I have to print a list of a set in c using linked lists (hence pointers). However,when I delete the first element of the list and try to print the list, it just displays a lot of addresses under each other. Any suggestions of what the problem might be? Thanks!

Delete function:

```
 int delete(set_element* src, int elem){
 if (src==NULL) {
    fputs("The list is empty.\n", stderr);
 }


 set_element* currElement;
 set_element* prevElement=NULL;

 for (currElement=src; currElement!=NULL; prevElement=currElement, currElement=currElement->next)     {
    if(currElement->value==elem) {
        if(prevElement==NULL){
            printf("Head is deleted\n");
            if(currElement->next!=NULL){
                *src = *currElement->next;
            } else {

                destroy(currElement);
            }
        } else {
            prevElement->next = currElement->next;
        }
        //  free(currElement);
        break;
    }
   }



return 1;
}



 void print(set_element* start)
{
    set_element *pt = start;

    while(pt != NULL)
    {
      printf("%d, ",pt->value);
     pt = pt->next;
   }
 }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code, but the issue is possibly that you are trying to print the list after freeing its head entry. Update any pointers to the list to point at the `head->next` entry, and you should be golden.

Comment: How are you printing the list?

Comment: You might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), it will help you write better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list pointer is the same as a pointer to the first element then the list pointer is no longer valid when you `free` the first element.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1. Let all your list methods take a pointer to the list so they can update it when neccesary. The problem with this approach is that if you have a copy of the pointer in another variable then that pointer gets invalidated too.
2. Don't let your list pointer point to the first element. Let it point to a pointer to the first element.

Sample Code:'

```
typedef struct node_struct {
  node_struct *next;
  void *data;
} Node;


typedef struct {
  Node *first;
} List;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** This answer contains inferred code.

A typical linked list in C looks a little something like this:

```
typedef struct _list List;
typedef struct _list_node ListNode;

struct _list {
  ListNode *head;
}

struct _list_node {
  void *payload;
  ListNode *next;
}
```

In order to correctly delete the first element from the list, the following sequence needs to take place:

```
List *aList; // contains a list

if (aList->head)
  ListNode *newHead = aList->head->next;

delete_payload(aList->head->payload); // Depending on what the payload actually is
free(aList->head);
aList->head = newHead;
```

The order of operations here is significant! Attempting to move the head without first freeing the old value will lead to a memory leak; and freeing the old head without first obtaining the correct value for the new head creates undefined behaviour.

**Addendum:** Occasionally, the `_list` portion of the above code will be omitted altogether, leaving lists and list nodes as the same thing; but from the symptoms you are describing, I'm guessing this is probably not the case here.

In such a situation, however, the steps remain, essentially, the same, but without the `aList->` bit.

---

**Edit:**

Now that I see your code, I can give you a more complete answer.

One of the key problems in your code is that it's all over the place. There is, however, one line in here that's particularly bad:

```
*src = *currElement->next;
```

This does not work, and is what is causing your crash.

In your case, the solution is either to wrap the linked list in some manner of container, like the struct _list construct above; or to rework your existing code to accept a pointer to a pointer to a set element, so that you can pass pointers to set elements (which is what you want to do) back.

In terms of performance, the two solutions are likely as close so as makes no odds, but using a wrapping list structure helps communicate intent. It also helps prevent other pointers to the list from becoming garbled as a result of head deletions, so there's that.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly your point. I changed the methods but it still does the same.
Code:
     void destroy(set_element* head)
    {
    set_element *current = head;
    set_element *temp;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
         temp = current;
         current = current->next;
         free(temp);
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when you delete a pointer (actually a piece of the memory) which doesn't belong to you. Double-check your function to make sure you're not freeing the same pointer you already freed, or freeing a pointer you didn't create with "malloc".